# Expandable / Collapsible UI component

Tags: android

I'm looking for the following Expandable/ Collapsible UI component.

### Before expanding

[image]

### After expanding

[image]

Anyone had came across such expandable UI component library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its called an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).